# Mapbox Android SDK with Raster Tile Layer or mbTiles

Tags: mapbox, android, mbtiles

Is it possible to add a raster TileLayer or mbTiles file as basemap of Android SDK? I do not want to use Mapbox Maps. I need to replace it with custom map with tile format or mbTiles. After Android SDK version 0.7 Mapbox revoke the mbTileLayer option. Is there any way to add this?

Comment: Do you consider analogs? NextGIS Mobile SDK (https://github.com/nextgis/android_maplib, http://docs.nextgis.com/ngmobile_dev/maplib/com/nextgis/maplib/api/IGISApplication.html) support raster tiles directly or via https://qms.nextgis.com/ service. The v3 (now in beta) will support OpenGL ES fast rendering on both Android and iOS (https://github.com/nextgis/ios.mobile.demo).

Comment: @DmitryBaryshnikov...Thanks, but It will not solve my problems. Mapbox SDK is more robust for development.

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/ffournier/TileProvider?files=1